# problem with [$node->language][0]

Tags: nodes, entities

I have a problem with this code in node.tpl.php

```
<?php if (isset($node->field_image[$node->language][0])): ?>
  <div class="image-block">
    <a href="<?php print $node_url ?>" title="<?php print $node->field_image[$node->language][0]['title'] ?>">
      <?php print theme(
        'image_style',
        array(
          'style_name' => 'teaser',
          'path' => $node->field_image[$node->language][0]['uri'],
          'alt' => $node->field_image[$node->language][0]['alt'],
          'title' => $node->field_image[$node->language][0]['title'],
          'attributes' => array(),
          'getsize' => false
        )
      );?>
    </a>
  </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

I know above code work if language natural, but my website is bilingual.
How can i solve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't be accessing the data directly. You should use [field_get_items()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.module/function/field_get_items/7) instead. I also use a foreach below, as that makes your code more generally applicable. Limiting to a single image should happen at the field layer, not theme. If you really want to, you could $image = [reset](http://php.net/manual/en/function.reset.php)($images).

```
$images = field_get_items('node', $node, 'field_image');
foreach ($images as $image) {
  $image_render = theme('image_style', array(
    'style_name' => 'teaser',
    'path' => $image['uri'],
    'alt' => $image['alt'],
    'title' => $image['title'],
    'attributes' => array(),
    'getsize' => false)
  );

  $link = l($image_render, $node_url, array('title' => $image['title'], 'html' => TRUE));
  print '<div class = "image-block">' . $link . '</div>';
}
```